# How to sum records if there are duplicates?

Tags: javascript

I have a loop, and among all the entries there are duplicate `well`.

```
R46 (135)
A5 (22)
A5 (514)
```

How to make sure that if duplicates appear, the value `sinking` summed.

In general, the result should be as follows:

```
R46 (135)
A5 (536)
```

I’m only interested in how to set the condition correctly when duplicating.

```js
 a = [{
            dataValues: {
                well: 'R46',
                sinking: 135
            }
        }, {
            dataValues: {
                well: 'A5',
                sinking: 514
            }
        },
        {
            dataValues: {
                well: 'A5',
                sinking: 22
            }
        }]

        var d = "";

        a.forEach((m) => {
            var well = m.dataValues.well;
            var sinking = m.dataValues.sinking;
            d = d + ' ' + well + ' ' + `(${sinking})`;
     
        });

        console.log(d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While iterating over the array, add the values to an object, whose properties are the well labels, and whose values are the cumulative `sinking`s for that well found so far. Then examine the object's entries at the end:

```js
const a = [{
    dataValues: {
      well: 'R46',
      sinking: 135
    }
  }, {
    dataValues: {
      well: 'A5',
      sinking: 514
    }
  },
  {
    dataValues: {
      well: 'A5',
      sinking: 22
    }
  }
];
const obj = {};
for (const { dataValues } of a) {
  const { well, sinking } = dataValues;
  obj[well] = (obj[well] || 0) + sinking;
}
for (const [well, totalSinking] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(`${well} (${totalSinking})`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a map to detect duplicate and to store summed value

```js
const result = {};

const a = [{
            dataValues: {
                well: 'R46',
                sinking: 135
            }
        }, {
            dataValues: {
                well: 'A5',
                sinking: 514
            }
        },
        {
            dataValues: {
                well: 'A5',
                sinking: 22
            }
        }]

        var d = "";

        a.forEach((m) => {
            const well = m.dataValues.well;
            const sinking = m.dataValues.sinking;
            if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(result, well)){ // duplicate
                result[well] += sinking;
            }else{
               result[well] = sinking;
            }      
        });

       for (well in result) {
           console.log(well , "(" + result[well] + ")")
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array as a map to keep running sums of all entries.

```
table = [];
for (entry in a) {
    obj = a[entry];
    if (table[obj.dataValues.well] === undefined) {
        table[obj.dataValues.well] = 0;
    }
    table[obj.dataValues.well] += obj.dataValues.sinking;
}
```

Then to print

```
for (entry in table) {
    console.log(entry, "(" + table[entry] + ")")
}
```